# Try/Catch Error when recalling previous Method in Java

Tags: java, try-catch, jgrasp

Using jGRASP for Mac, I'm writing code for a java program that will first ask the user to input an integer [limitNumber], then calculate the odd numbers between 1 and [limitNumber] and display the sum of those numbers and display the value.  After the first methods run, the program will then ask the user if they wish to run the calculation again with a new integer.

To continue, the user is prompted to input a 1 for yes and a 0 for no. If either of those numbers are entered, the program runs fine, but I'm having difficulty trying to incorporate another try/catch that will focus on the 1 and 0 specifically and throw the exception message for any other value entered.

The code is as follows: the try/catch I'm trying to figure out is in the doAgain() Method

```
 import java.util.Scanner; //PRE-WRITTEN CODE FROM SCANNER CLASS

public class sumOddsPetrantoni {

    public static int limitNumber;

    public static void main(String args[]) // MAIN METHOD USED TO CALL OTHER
                                            // METHODS
    { //
        getLimitNumber(); // USER INPUTS NUMBER TO BE USED AS MAX LIMIT
                            //
        calcSumPrint(); // COMP CALCS ODD #S BETWEEN 1 AND LIMIT NUMBER
                        //
        doAgain(); // ASKS USER IF THEY WANT TO REPEAT THE PROCESS
                    // YES: RETURNS TO getLimitNumber METHOD
                    // NO: TERMINATES PROGRAM
                    //
    } // END OF MAIN METHOD

    public static void getLimitNumber() {

        boolean done = false;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (done != true) {
            try {
                System.out.print("Let's add some odd numbers!");
                System.out
                        .print("\nPlease enter the limit number as an integer: ");
                limitNumber = input.nextInt(); // METHOD USED TO INPUT INTEGER
                done = true;
            } // END - TRY SECTION
            catch (Exception message) {
                input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("\nDo you know what an integerer is?");
                System.out.println("The program threw a " + message
                        + " message at me, NOT a real integer.");
                System.out.println("Please try again.\n");

            } // END - CATCH SECTION
        } // END - WHILE LOOP

    } // END - GET LIMIT NUMBER METHOD

    public static void calcSumPrint() { // START - CALC SUM PRINT METOD

        int sum = 0;
        int ctr = 0;
        for (ctr = 1; ctr <= limitNumber; ctr += 2)
            // START - FOR LOOP
            sum = sum + ctr;
        {
            System.out.println("\nThe sum of the odd numbers between 1 and "
                    + limitNumber + " is " + sum + ".");
        } // END - FOR LOOP

    } // END - CALC SUM PRINT METHOD

    public static void doAgain() { // START - DO AGAIN METHOD

        int ans;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out
                .println("That was aewsome! \nWant to give it another shot? \n(1 to Continue, 0 to Quit): ");
        ans = input.nextInt();

        if (ans == 1) {
            System.out.println("\nLet's rock and roll!");
            getLimitNumber();
            calcSumPrint();
            doAgain();
        }
        if (ans == 0) {
            System.out.println("Fine, I see how it is...");
        }

    } // END - DO AGAIN METHOD

}
```

Comment: JavaScript has nothing to do with Java. Removed tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner; //PRE-WRITTEN CODE FROM SCANNER CLASS

public class sumOddsPetrantoni {

    public static int limitNumber;

    public static void main(String args[]) // MAIN METHOD USED TO CALL OTHER
                                            // METHODS
    { //
        getLimitNumber(); // USER INPUTS NUMBER TO BE USED AS MAX LIMIT
                            //
        calcSumPrint(); // COMP CALCS ODD #S BETWEEN 1 AND LIMIT NUMBER
                        //
        doAgain(); // ASKS USER IF THEY WANT TO REPEAT THE PROCESS
                    // YES: RETURNS TO getLimitNumber METHOD
                    // NO: TERMINATES PROGRAM
                    //
    } // END OF MAIN METHOD

    public static void getLimitNumber() {

        boolean done = false;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (done != true) {
            try {
                System.out.print("Let's add some odd numbers!");
                System.out
                        .print("\nPlease enter the limit number as an integer: ");
                limitNumber = input.nextInt(); // METHOD USED TO INPUT INTEGER
                done = true;
            } // END - TRY SECTION
            catch (Exception message) {
                input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("\nDo you know what an integerer is?");
                System.out.println("The program threw a " + message
                        + " message at me, NOT a real integer.");
                System.out.println("Please try again.\n");

            } // END - CATCH SECTION
        } // END - WHILE LOOP

    } // END - GET LIMIT NUMBER METHOD

    public static void calcSumPrint() { // START - CALC SUM PRINT METOD

        int sum = 0;
        int ctr = 0;
        for (ctr = 1; ctr <= limitNumber; ctr += 2)
            // START - FOR LOOP
            sum = sum + ctr;
        {
            System.out.println("\nThe sum of the odd numbers between 1 and "
                    + limitNumber + " is " + sum + ".");
        } // END - FOR LOOP

    } // END - CALC SUM PRINT METHOD

    public static int getInt(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ans;
        try {

            ans = input.nextInt();
            return ans;
         }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Try Again");
            ans = getInt();
        }
        return ans;
    }
    public static void doAgain() { // START - DO AGAIN METHOD

        int ans;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out
                .println("That was aewsome! \nWant to give it another shot? \n(1 to Continue, 0 to Quit): ");

             ans = getInt();

        if (ans == 1) {
            System.out.println("\nLet's rock and roll!");
            getLimitNumber();
            calcSumPrint();
            doAgain();
        }
        else if (ans == 0) {
            System.out.println("Fine, I see how it is...");
        }else{
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Oops! that's not fair input must be 0 or 1");
        }



    } // END - DO AGAIN METHOD

}
```

use this it handle the exception :)

Comment: @NickPetrantoni try this..!

Comment: thanks brother! Just had to move the 'if' and 'else if' statements into the try and now everything is working perfectly.

Comment: Welcome @NickPetrantoni checkout the **getInt()** method it does a recursive call untill correct  no is read ..:)

Answer (score 0):

You can do following at the and of your doAgain() method:

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException(ans + " is not allowed value. Only 0 or 1 is allowed");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use an else clause and restart the method?

```
if(ans == 1)
  {
  System.out.println("\nLet's rock and roll!");
  getLimitNumber();
  calcSumPrint();
  doAgain();
  }
else if(ans == 0)
  {
  System.out.println("Fine, I see how it is...");
  } 
else {
  System.out.println("What you talkin bout, Willis");
  doAgain();
 }
```

Comment: this is working great for numbers, but throws the same exception error when a letter is typed in, would there be a different else for numbers vs. letters?

Comment: @NickPetrantoni throws what?

Comment: Want to give it another shot? 

(1 to Continue, 0 to Quit): 

D

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)

 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)

 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
 at sumOddsPetrantoni.doAgain(sumOddsPetrantoni.java:76)
 at sumOddsPetrantoni.main(sumOddsPetrantoni.java:29)